# Is the first excited state of a superconducting qubit a stationary state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity, quantum-computer

A superconducting qubit is essentially an anharmonic oscillator with uneven spacings of the eigenstates. These states are eigenstates of the overall hamiltonian, which should mean that it is an energy eigenstate. This then seems to imply that like all energy eigenstates it evolves in time as such:

$$
\psi (t) = e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}E_nt}\psi(0)
$$

Which would still leave $ |\psi(t)|^2$ invariant over time. Given that the superconducting wave function can be equated to this:

$$
 \psi(r) = \sqrt{\rho(r)}e^{-i\theta(r)}
$$
Where $\rho(r)$ is the Cooper pair number density. This evolves in time as such:
$$
\psi(r, t) = \sqrt{\rho(r)}e^{-i\theta(r)}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}E_nt}
$$
Which means the probability distribution stays constant over time:
$$
|\psi(r, t)|^2 = \rho(r)
$$

This seems to imply that the first excited state (and the ground state) has no change in number density, i.e. no current flow. This seems very unintuitive given that qubit can be seen as an LC circuit. Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

so you are confusing a superconductor whose macroscopic wavefunction describing only the ground state could be described the way you did, with a superconducting qubit which has a totally different wavefunction and is a junction between two blobs of superconducting material.

this introductory article might straighten things out: 
http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.1897